# How do I get Tailwind UI navbar hamburger menu to function inside my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I'm a beginner React developer and am attempting to incorporate Tailwind UI's new navbar component into my React app. I used the [TailwingUI Navbars](https://tailwindui.com/preview) code snip as a starting point and modified the HTML into JSX to the best of my ability. I have everything rendering correctly except for the mobile view hamburger menu. Currently, onClick nothing happens.

[Here is a Loom video of the error.](https://www.loom.com/share/2b7640c5846f493b98c5f62d30a5a7cc)

Ideally, I would like to see a list of the navbar items appear in a box, as shown in the example on Tailwind UI's website. What would be the best way to incorporate this functionality using Tailwind CSS?

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function ClientNav() {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav class="bg-blue">
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <div class="relative flex items-center justify-between h-16">
                        <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
                            {/* Hamburger Menu */}
                            <button class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-white hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                                <svg class="block h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                                </svg>
                                <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-1 flex items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
                            {/* Logo */}
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
                                <img class="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto" src="./sbcr-logo-transparent-white-bg.png" alt="Surf Break Costa Rica Logo"></img>
                                <img class="hidden lg:block h-8 w-auto" src="./sbcr-logo-transparent-white-bg.png" alt="Surf Break Costa Rica logo"></img>
                            </div>
                            {/* Nav Items */}
                            <div class="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6">
                                <div class="flex space-x-4">
                                    <a href="/home" class="bg-turquoise text-white hover:bg-turquoise-dark px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Dashboard</a>
                                    <a href="/flightinfo" class="text-white hover:bg-turquoise hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Flight Info</a>
                                    <a href="/releaseform" class="text-white hover:bg-turquoise hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Release Form</a>
                                    <a href="/itinerary" class="text-white hover:bg-turquoise hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Itinerary</a>
                                    <a href="/photos" class="text-white hover:bg-turquoise hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Photos</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
                            {/* Notification Icon */}
                            <button class="bg-turquoise p-1 rounded-full text-white hover:bg-turquoise-dark focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
                                <span class="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                                <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden sm:hidden">
                    <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
                        <a href="/" class="bg-blue text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Dashboard</a>
                        <a href="/flightinfo" class="text-white hover:bg-turquoise hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Flight Info</a>
                        <a href="/releaseforms" class="text-white hover:bg-turquoise hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Release Forms</a>
                        <a href="/itinerary" class="text-white hover:bg-turquoise hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Itinerary</a>
                        <a href="/photos" class="text-white hover:bg-turquoise hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Photos</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

### The HTML to return inside REACT will be.

---

```js
document.getElementById('togglemebutton').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("resultnav").classList.toggle("hidden");
}

//document.getElementById('togglemebutton').onclick = function () {
//  document.getElementById("toggleme").classList.toggle("hidden");
//}


const toggleprofile = document.getElementById("toggleprofile");
const resultprofile = document.getElementById("resultprofile");
[...document.querySelectorAll('body')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.parentElement.id !== "toggleprofile") {
      console.clear();
      console.log(event.target.parentElement.id)
      resultprofile.classList.add("hidden")
    }else{
    resultprofile.classList.toggle("hidden")}
  })
})
```

```css
body{
height:350px}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="bg-gray-800">
  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="relative flex items-center justify-between h-16">
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
        <!-- Mobile menu button-->
        <button id="togglemebutton" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 focus:text-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out" aria-label="Main menu"
          aria-expanded="false">
          <!-- Icon when menu is closed. -->
          <!-- Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" -->
          <svg class="block h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
          <!-- Icon when menu is open. -->
          <!-- Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" -->
          <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1 flex items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
          <img class="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
          <img class="hidden lg:block h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
        </div>
        <div class="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6">
          <div class="flex">
            <a href="#" class="px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Team</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Calendar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
        <button class="p-1 border-2 border-transparent text-gray-400 rounded-full hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" aria-label="Notifications">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
          </svg>
        </button>

        <!-- Profile dropdown -->
        <div class="ml-3 relative">
          <div>
            <button id="toggleprofile" class="flex text-sm border-2 border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out" id="user-menu" aria-label="User menu" aria-haspopup="true">
              <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
            </button>
          </div>
          <!--
            Profile dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.

            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
              From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
              From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
              To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          -->
          <div id="resultprofile" class="hidden z-40 origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg">
            <div class="py-1 rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Your Profile</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Settings</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Sign out</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--
    Mobile menu, toggle classes based on menu state.

    Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden"
  -->
  <div id="resultnav" class="hidden sm:hidden">
    <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3">
      <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Dashboard</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Team</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Projects</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Calendar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Use script tag inside HTML or outside.
You needed to just use event listener on all elements in the javascript.
I'm also using react and I made it work for me**

**Remember:** There's no need to add CSS which I used body{...} as it is just to change element's height inside the post.